# jQplot Animate Series Separately on show

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jqplot

This is my scenario:

I want a series from a barRendered graph to animate from top to bottom when is showed.
If this posible and if yes how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The settings passed into the $.jqplot method should include:

animate: true,
animateReplot: true

I am not sure what version of jqplot got the update of animation, but I know that their most recent version (1.0.3) allows it.

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barLineAnimated.html